# How to pass the test data through property file to run the tests in AWS DeviceForm

Tags: android, maven, amazon-web-services

My framework is implemented with maven and the respective plugins suggested by AWS DeviceFarm is added in pom.xml.

I Am able to run the scripts locally on my machine with the below maven run parameters:

```
-DconfigPath=/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/MobileTestData/android.properties

Note: configPath consists of UserName, Password etc.,.
```

I need to do the same with AWS deviceFarm, anyone one please suggest me how to do the same with AWS device form.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by building a .jar file with .property file/Test data and loading this with a class loader function.